# How to Change the defaults in Great Expectations DataDoc HTML Report?

Tags: html, great-expectations

Great Expectations provides the ability to produce Html reports using DataDocs as shown in the folloiwng example:

[image]

I would like the change the following defaults in the header - see image

[image]

The report is generated using the following

```
validation_results_stg = ge_stg_update.validate(expectation_suite='stg_expectations.html', only_return_failures=False)
```

I believe I can make changes because if I run the code `validatation_results_stg`

I get the following output

```
{
  "evaluation_parameters": {},
  "meta": {
    "great_expectations_version": "0.13.38",
    "expectation_suite_name": "default",
    "run_id": {
      "run_time": "2021-11-18T14:59:49.831733+00:00",
      "run_name": null
    },
    "batch_kwargs": {
      "ge_batch_id": "2c157d12-4880-11ec-8b5e-000d3ad66fea"
    },
    "batch_markers": {},
    "batch_parameters": {},
    "validation_time": "20211118T145949.831530Z",
    "expectation_suite_meta": {
      "great_expectations_version": "0.13.38"
    }
  },
  "results": [
    {
      "result": {
        "element_count": 14539,
        "missing_count": 0,
        "missing_percent": 0.0,
        "unexpected_count": 0,
        "unexpected_percent": 0.0,
        "unexpected_percent_total": 0.0,
        "unexpected_percent_nonmissing": 0.0,
        "partial_unexpected_list": []
      },
      "exception_info": {
        "raised_exception": false,
        "exception_message": null,
        "exception_traceback": null
      },
      "meta": {},
      "success": true,
      "expectation_config": {
        "kwargs": {
          "column": "SERVICE",
          "value_set": [
            "CMC",
            "Divorce",
            "Probate",
            "SSCS"
          ]
        },
        "expectation_type": "expect_column_values_to_be_in_set",
        "meta": {},
        "ge_cloud_id": null
      }
    },
    {
      "result": {
        "observed_value": 14539
      },
      "exception_info": {
        "raised_exception": false,
        "exception_message": null,
        "exception_traceback": null
      },
      "meta": {},
      "success": true,
      "expectation_config": {
        "kwargs": {
          "value": 14539
        },
        "expectation_type": "expect_table_row_count_to_equal",
        "meta": {},
        "ge_cloud_id": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "success": true,
  "statistics": {
    "evaluated_expectations": 2,
    "successful_expectations": 2,
    "unsuccessful_expectations": 0,
    "success_percent": 100.0
  }
}
```

As you can see the defaults are loaded e.g. you will notice  `"expectation_suite_name": "default",`

Can someone show me how you can the default to something else?

Comment: How is this related to Spark?

Comment: I should have mentioned that this question was implemented on Apache Spark on Synapse